# Umbraco and dynamic URL content at root level

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, umbraco

I need to port a website to asp.net and decided to use Umbraco as the underlying CMS.

The issue I'm having is I need to retain the URL structure of the current site.

The current URL template looks like the following

```
domain.com/{brand}/{product}
```

This is hard to make a route for since it mixes in with all the other content on the site. Like `domain.com/foo/bar` which is not a brand or product.

I've coded up a `IContentFinder`, and injected it into the Umbraco pipeline, that check the URL structure and determins if `domain.com/{brand}` matches any of the known brands on the site, in which case i find the content by its internal route `domain.com/products/` and pass along `{brand}/{model}` as `HttpContext Items`  and return it using the `IContentFinder`.

This works, but it also means no MVC controller is called. So now I'm left with fetching from the database in the cshtml file which is not so pretty and kind of breaks MVC conventions.

What i really wan't is to take the url `domain.com/{brand}/{product}` and rewrite it to `domain.com/products/{brand}/{product}` and then being able to hit a ProductsController serving up the content based on the parameters brand and product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

It depends a bit on your content setup. If your products exist as pages in Umbraco, then I think you are on the right path.

In your content finder, remember to set the page you've found on the request like this `request.PublishedContent = content;`

Then you can take advantage of Route Hijacking to add a ProductController that will get called for that request: https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-controllers

Example implementation:

```
protected bool TryFindContent(PublishedContentRequest docReq, string docType)
{
    var segments = docReq.Uri.GetAbsolutePathDecoded().Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] exceptLast = segments.Take(segments.Length - 1).ToArray();

    string toMatch = string.Format("/{0}", string.Join("/", exceptLast));

    var found = docReq.RoutingContext.UmbracoContext.ContentCache.GetByRoute(toMatch);
    if (found != null && found.DocumentTypeAlias == docType)
    {
        docReq.PublishedContent = found;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public class ProductContentFinder : DoctypeContentFinderBase
{
    public override bool TryFindContent(PublishedContentRequest contentRequest)
    {
        // The "productPage" here is the alias of your documenttype
        return TryFindContent(contentRequest, "productPage");
    }
}

public class ProductPageController : RenderMvcController {}
```

In the example the document type has an alias of "productPage". That means that the controller needs to be named exactly "ProductPageController" and inherit the RenderMvcController.

Notice that it does not matter what the actual pages name is.

Comment: I only have a single page at domain.com/Porducts/ in the content tree, i get the products from an external source. In the IContentFinder i set PublishedContent by using the ContentCache.GetByRoute("Products/") bit it do not appear to trigger by ProductsController, The Products content item has its own document type and template.
I got it to work by inserting a Html.RenderAction() on the template and pointing it to the ProductsController. But i dont think its very pretty and why can't i hit the ProductsController in the first place when calling GetByRoute("Products/").

Comment: @CodeMonkey Ok, I included some sample code from a project where I do almost what you are looking for. In my case it will cut segments off the url until in matches the document type you supply.

Then you could combine that with a url rewrite, that reqrites "brand/sku" to "products/brand/sku", and the above code should get you going.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this once I get home. How do the action of the ProductPageController fit into all this? Should my ProductPage content item in the Umbraco content tree have a template assigned or should i rely on the controller to return a view(cshtml)?

Comment: Your Index(RenderModel model) will get the "Products" node. If you return the base.Index(model), then it will use the template that the editor selected in Umbraco. You can also choose to return any mvc view you like, just like a regular controller.

Comment: do you know how i get the parameters, that being {brand} and {product}, into the controller? I need them in the ProductsPageController to fetch the corretct model from the external service.

Comment: I haven't found a nice way to do that yet, so basically I'm currently parsing the url twice. But you could probably do the parsing in the content finder, and pass it via http context items,  or maybe extend the rendermodel somehow to pass it to the controller.

Comment: I got it working, so thanks for the help. Its not the prettiest solution i think, since its a bit to magic for me but i guess thats asp.net MVC in a nutshell with all its convention based routing and umbraco building on top of it.